# sencha multiple filter in one property

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am creating a grid and i want to be able to insert multiple Not Filters.

I have a grid of invitations

then i add the filter

```
store.addFilter(
[{ property: 'invitationStatus',
operator: '<>',
value: 'IN_PROGRESS'
},
{
property: 'invitationStatus',
operator: '<>',
value: 'SENT_BY_COMPANY'
},
{
property: 'invitationStatus',
operator: '<>',
value: 'SENT_BY_SYSTEM'
}]);
```

But the only filter applyed is:

```
{
property: 'invitationStatus',
operator: '<>',
value: 'SENT_BY_SYSTEM'
}
```

How can i change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seems to be an `<>` in the [operators list](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.util.Filter.html#cfg-operator). In your case, the suitable operator is `notin`, passing as value an array of elements that you don't want to be included in the filtered results.
Something like this:

```
store.addFilter({
    property: 'invitationStatus',
    operator: 'notin',
    value: ['IN_PROGRESS', 'SENT_BY_COMPANY', 'SENT_BY_SYSTEM']
});
```

Comment: the <> filter works like != but it looks like it works like a charm